# I can't change the value of my variable

Tags: python, project

I'm making a game about crafting and i can't change the value of a variable and i don't know why. Here is a bit of my code:

```
#Setting Up
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sapling = 3
log = 0
twig = 0
stick = 0
boulder = 5
pickaxe = 1
axe = 1
coal = 0
torch = 0
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Inventory
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
inventory = {
    "sapling" : sapling,
    "log" : log,
    "twig" : twig,
    "stick" : stick,
    "boulder" : boulder,
    "pickaxe" : pickaxe,
    "axe" : axe,
    "coal" : coal,
    "torch" : torch,
    }
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#InGameItems
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
game = {
    "Items =",
    "sapling",
    "log",
    "twig",
    "stick",
    "boulder",
    "pickaxe",
    "axe",
    "coal",
    "torch",
    }
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Help
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
h = {
    "(i)" : "To access inventory",
    "(?)" : "For help",
    "(g)" : "To check out all in game items",
    "plant (item)" : "To plant item",
    "craft (item)" : "To craft an item",
    }
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Begin Code
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
print("To ask for help type (?)")
while 1:
    player = input(":")
    if player == "?":
        print(h)
    if player == "i":
        print(inventory)
    if player == "g":
        print(game)
    if player == "plant sapling" and sapling != 0 and axe != 0:
        print("Planting")
        print("You planted a sapling!")
        print("Your sapling turned into a tree!")
        print("Cutting tree")
        print("2 logs gained!")
        log += 2
        sapling -= 1
```

so right here is my problem, i am increasing the value of log, but when i play the game log doesn't increase. I can't seem to find out how to increase the value of log.

Comment: There is a big difference between a variable and a dict value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
inventory = {
    ...
    "log" : log
    ...
}
```

You're duplicating the reference of `log` (`0`) inside `inventory`, but when you do `log += 2` you're not really changing the value of `log`, you're creating a temporary variable which is `log + 2` and linking it to the name `log`. the `log` inside `inventory` still references the old `log`, which is `0`.

So instead of `log += 2` you should do `inventory["log"] += 2`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you could do that in python!

Comment: @youngprogrammer thumb the answer up and click accept if this answer helped you.

Comment: It may help to think of both `log` and `inventory['log']` as names, not variables. At the start, they're both names for the exact same value, the number 0. And you can't change the number 0 to have a different value, or you'd break all of physics, math, and logic.

Answer (score -1):

You have run afoul of the fact that your dictionaries are being constructed *by value* rather than *by reference*. Specifically, the dictionary entry

```
"log": log
```

does *not* mean "the value for the key "log" will be whatever happens to be in the `log` variable at the time". What it means is "take the current value of `log`, and *copy* it to be the value of the dictionary entry with key "log". You now have two separate values, not one value and a reference to that value. The dictionary has its own value for the key "log" that's an integer that happens to be `0`, and `log` is a completely separate variable containing the integer `0`. Changing one will not affect the other. Instead of `log += 2`, you would need to put:

```
inventory["log"] += 2
```

Comment: This is wrong. The dictionary is holding a reference to the exact same number `0` that `log` is holding; values are _never_ implicitly copied in Python. What's happening is that `0` is an immutable value, so `log += 2` doesn't change the value `0` into `0+2`, it creates a new value and binds `log` to that.

Comment: You're right, that's what I meant but I failed to explain that.